# System to automatically login to my university's Wi-Fi network using HTTP request

Tags: python, console, http, authentication, logging

### What is this?

My university's Wi-Fi network requires students to visit a specific URL and login to the network before we can use the actual internet. This project replicates that same process by calling just one command, and I've successfully implemented it using Windows Task Scheduler and some `cron` black magic on Ubuntu.

This was designed as a two month-long test running on small number of close friends' computers. We'll manually take their log data and look for any unexpected events. The final version will use Flutter/Dart to make a cross-platform experience. As a consequence:

- credentials are stored in plaintext only for this testing project (however it must be sent in plaintext to the server, so there's no way around that)
- the final implementation will be a service/daemon
- the final implementation will involve a GUI.

That said, I'd like to see if there are any improvements possible in this code. FYI, I'm working with university officials to make sure we don't do something we're not allowed to, and all users are fully explained about any data being collected.

### Key concepts

- Each user will give their credentials to the software during set up.
- The operating system will call the script `python login_cli.py login` whenever the computer connects to a Wi-Fi network.
- From there, we'll look at sending requests, parsing responses, handle errors, keeping the user informed etc.

### Files

(ignoring convential ones like `README` and `requirements.txt`)

| File | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `src/auth.py` | Handle all communications with the serve, and parse its responses (when applicable). |
| `src/credentials.py` | Handle all credentials-related file operations. |
| `login_cli.py` | The main UI and integration. Also handles logging, exceptions, and notifications. |

Note that terms specific to my university have been replaced with generic terms.

---

### `src/auth.py`

```py
"""
communicate with the server
- defines login/logout headers and URLs
- sends the login/logout requests
- parses the server responses
"""

from http.client import OK
from logging import getLogger
from os import popen
from platform import system as get_os_name
from re import compile as re_compile

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import ConnectionError, get, post

# URLs for the service
LOGIN_URL = "http://wifi.university-name.domain/some/page/authlogin"
LOGOUT_URL = "http://wifi.university-name.domain/some/page/authlogout"

# HTML parser to understand server response
HTML_PARSER = 'html.parser'

# Regex for SSIDs at UNIVERSITY_NAME
SSID_REGEX = (
    re_compile(r"UNIVERSITY_NAME *2\.4 *G? *\d*"),
    re_compile(r"UNIVERSITY_NAME *5 *G? *\d*"),
    re_compile(r"test *\d*")
)

# create a logger for this module
logger = getLogger(__name__)

def get_ssid() -> str:
    """get the SSID of the network the user is connected to
    - detect the operating system
    - use the appropriate shell command to get the SSID
    - return the SSID"""

    os_name = get_os_name()
    logger.debug(f"Detected OS: {os_name}")

    if os_name == 'Windows':
        output = popen("netsh wlan show interfaces").read()
        status = output.split("State")[1].split(":")[1].split('\n')[0].strip()

        if status != "connected":
            raise ConnectionError("Not connected to any Wi-Fi network.")

        ssid = output.split("SSID")[1].split(":")[1].split('\n')[0].strip()

    elif os_name == 'Linux':
        output = popen("iwgetid").read()
        status = output.split(" ")[0].strip()

        if "SSID" not in output:
            raise ConnectionError("Not connected to any Wi-Fi network.")

        ssid = output.split('"')[1]

    elif os_name == 'Darwin':
        output = popen("ipconfig getsummary en0 | grep -e \" *SSID\"").read()

        if "SSID" not in output:
            raise ConnectionError("Not connected to any Wi-Fi network.")

        ssid = output.split("SSID :")[1].strip()

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"Unsupported OS: {os_name}")

    logger.info(f"Detected SSID: {ssid}")
    return ssid


def check_ssid(ssid: str) -> bool:
    """check if the user is connected to a UNIVERSITY_NAME network
    - check if the SSID matches the regex for UNIVERSITY_NAME networks
    - return True if connected to a UNIVERSITY_NAME network, False otherwise"""

    return any(map(
        lambda regex: regex.match(ssid),
        SSID_REGEX
    ))


def parse_login_response(html: bytes) -> str:
    """parse login HTML response
    - parse using BeautifulSoup
    - read the contents to determine request outcome
    - return a custom string containing status information
    - if page has unexpected/invalid content, raise an exception
    
    steps:
    1. check page title element
    2. if page title element exists, check its value
    3. if page title element is expected/valid, return status
    4. if page title element was ambiguous, check error element
    5. if page title element didn't exist, check page contents"""

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, HTML_PARSER)

    # if title is not none, proceed and store its value to `title`
    if title := soup.find('title'):
        clean_title = title.text.strip().lower()

        if clean_title == "successful wifi-provider-company authentication":
            return 'login-success'

        elif clean_title == "active session exist":
            return 'session-exists'
        
        elif clean_title == "this is the default server vhost":
            return 'not-on-university_name'

        # check error elements if we get back a generic title
        elif clean_title == "university-wifi-department authentication":
            error = soup.find('td', {'class': "errorText10"}).text.strip().lower()  # type: ignore

            standard_errors = {
                "sorry, please check your username and password and try again.": 'password-failure',
                "sorry, that account does not exist.": 'id-failure'
            }

            if error in standard_errors:
                return standard_errors[error]

            else:
                logger.warning(html)
                raise ValueError(f"Got title \"{title}\" but invalid error \"{error}\".")

        else:
            logger.warning(html)
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid title \"{title}\".")

    elif soup.find('b') and soup.find('b').text.strip().lower() == "you are already logged in":  # type: ignore
        return 'session-exists'

    else:
        logger.warning(html)
        raise ValueError("Invalid page.")


def parse_logout_response(html: bytes) -> str:
    """parse logout HTML response
    - parse using BeautifulSoup
    - read the contents to determine request outcome
    - return a custom string containing status information
    - if page has unexpected/invalid content, raise an exception
    
    steps:
    1. check page title element
    2. if page title element exists, check its value
    3. if page title element is expected/valid, return status"""

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, HTML_PARSER)

    if title := soup.find('title'):
        clean_title = title.text.strip().lower()

        if clean_title == "logout failure":
            return 'logout-failure'

        elif clean_title == "logout successful":
            return 'logout-success'

        else:
            logger.warning(html)
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid title \"{clean_title}\".")
            
    else:
        logger.warning(html)
        raise ValueError("Invalid page.")


def login(credentials: dict[str, str]) -> str:
    """main login HTTP request
    - create the request
    - send the request
    - return the response"""

    login_payload = {
        'serviceName': 'WiFiProviderCompany',
        'Submit22': 'Login',
        'userId': credentials['register-number'],
        'password': credentials['password']
    }

    try:
        login_request = post(
            LOGIN_URL,
            data=login_payload
        )

    except ConnectionError as e:
        raise ConnectionError(f"Server-side error. Contact IT_SUPPORT or wait until morning.") from e

    # analyse the HTTP status code and (if available) response
    if int(login_request.status_code == OK):
        logger.info("Login request acknowledged.")
        logger.info(f"Status code {login_request.status_code}.")

        parsed_response_status = parse_login_response(login_request.content)
        logger.info("Response parsed.")

        return parsed_response_status

    else:
        logger.warning(login_request.content)
        raise ConnectionError(f"The server returned status code {login_request.status_code}.")


def logout() -> str:
    """main login HTTP request
    - create the request
    - send the request
    - return the response"""

    try:
        logout_request = get(
        url=LOGOUT_URL
    )

    except ConnectionError as e:
        raise ConnectionError(f"Server-side error. Contact IT_SUPPORT or wait until morning.") from e

    # analyse the HTTP status code and (if available) response
    if int(logout_request.status_code == OK):
        logger.info("Logout request acknowledged.")
        logger.info(f"Status code {logout_request.status_code}.")

        parsed_response_status = parse_logout_response(logout_request.content)
        logger.info("Response parsed.")

        return parsed_response_status

    else:
        logger.warning(logout_request.content)
        raise ConnectionError(f"The server returned status code {logout_request.status_code}.")
```

### `src/credentials.py`

```py
"""
manage user credentials
- reads credentials from the user
- creates/edits/deletes credentials file
- reads credentials from files
"""

from json import dump, load
from logging import getLogger
from pathlib import Path
from re import compile

## regex for validating the register number
# first two characters must be digits, followed by three uppercase letters, and must end in four digits
REGISTER_NUMBER_REGEX = compile(r"^(?P<year>\d{2})(?P<course>[A-Z]{3})(?P<student_number>\d{4}$)")

# create a logger for this module
logger = getLogger(__name__)


def add_credentials(credentials_file_path: Path, register_number: str, password: str) -> None:
    """save or edit credentials
    - save the data to file"""

    # create a dictionary because we shall save as JSON
    credentials = {
        'register-number': register_number,
        'password': password
    }

    # if credentials already exist, overwrite to edit
    if credentials_file_path.exists():
        logger.info("Credentials file already exists. Overwriting.")

    # if credentials do not exist, create a new file
    else:
        logger.info("Credentials file does not exist. Creating.")
        credentials_file_path.touch(exist_ok=True)

    with open(credentials_file_path, 'w') as credentials_file:
        logger.info("Credentials file found.")
        dump(credentials, credentials_file, indent=4)

    logger.info("Dumped credentials to file.")


def purge_credentials(credentials_file_path: Path) -> None:
    """purge existing credentials
    - raise an exception if credentials file doesn't exist"""

    if not credentials_file_path.exists():
        raise FileNotFoundError("Credentials file does not exist.")

    logger.info("Credentials file found.")

    credentials_file_path.unlink()

    if not credentials_file_path.exists():
        logger.info("Deleted credentials file.")


def load_credentials(credentials_file_path: Path) -> dict[str, str]:
    """load credentials form file
    - raise an exception if credentials file doesn't exist"""

    if credentials_file_path.exists():
        logger.info("Credentials file found.")

        with open(credentials_file_path, 'r') as credentials_file:
            credentials = load(credentials_file)

            logger.info("Loaded credentials.")
            return credentials

    raise FileNotFoundError("Credentials file does not exist.")
```

### `login_cli.py`

```py
"""
- integrate the entire application
- define the CLI and serve the it
- handle user settings
- handle logging
- handle notifications
- handle exceptions
"""

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from argparse import Namespace as ArgNamespace
from getpass import getpass
from json import JSONDecodeError, dump, loads
from logging import DEBUG, INFO, FileHandler, Formatter, Logger, getLogger
from os import environ
from pathlib import Path
from sys import argv

from colorama import Fore, Style
from notifypy import Notify

import src.auth
import src.credentials

# set the logger level
LOGGER_LEVEL = INFO

# set a scheme for the notifying the user based on custom status messages
# in general, the user is notified only of failures or other abnormal events
# the user is not notified if they are expected to be active on a command line
DEFAULT_USER_NOTIFICATION_SCHEME: dict[str, dict[str, str | bool]] = {
    'login-success': {
        'notification': False,
        'title': "Login successful",
        'message': "Logged in to the Wi-Fi network.",
    },
    'password-failure': {
        'notification': True,
        'message': "Incorrect password",
        'title': "Login failed",
    },
    'id-failure': {
        'notification': True,
        'message': "Invalid register number",
        'title': "Login failed",
    },
    'no-credentials': {
        'notification': True,
        'title': "Login failed",
        'message': "No credentials found. Please create then using the command \"wicon addcreds\"."
    },
    'session-exists': {
        'notification': True,
        'message': "Already logged in",
        'title': "Login successful",
    },
    'logout-failure': {
        'notification': True,
        'message': "Logout failed",
        'title': "Possibly server error",
    },
    'logout-success': {
        'notification': True,
        'message': "Logout successful",
        'title': "Logged out of the Wi-Fi network",
    },
    'not-on-university_name': {
        'notification': False
    },
    'credadd-success': {
        'notification': False
    },
    'credadd-failure': {
        'notification': False
    },
    'credpurge-success': {
        'notification': False
    },
    'credpurge-failure': {
        'notification': False
    }
}

# raise a default notification in case of a key error
DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION: dict[str, str | bool] = {
    'notification': True,
    'title': "Unknown Status",
    'message': "Please send the log file to the developer.",
}


def load_settings(settings_file_path: Path, logger: Logger) -> dict[str, dict[str, dict[str, str | bool]]]:
    """load the user settings from the settings file
    - if the file does not exist, create it and return the default settings"""

    if settings_file_path.exists():
        with open(settings_file_path, 'r') as settings_file:
            settings = settings_file.read().strip()

            if settings:
                try:
                    USER_SETTINGS = loads(settings)

                except JSONDecodeError as e:
                    logger.warn(settings)
                    raise ValueError("Invalid settings JSON.") from e

                else:
                    logger.info("Settings file found and loaded.")
                    return USER_SETTINGS

    settings_file_path.touch()
    with open(settings_file_path, 'w') as settings_file:
        logger.info("Creating settings file with default settings.")

        USER_SETTINGS = {
            "notification-settings": DEFAULT_USER_NOTIFICATION_SCHEME
        }

        dump(USER_SETTINGS, settings_file, indent=4)
        logger.info("Settings file created.")

    return USER_SETTINGS


def init(__name__: str) -> tuple[dict[str, dict[str, dict[str, str | bool]]], Path, Logger]:
    """initialize objects for later use
    - set file path objects for credentials and logging
    - configure the loggers
    """

    # handle cases where the folder is not the default
    if (folder_name := environ.get('DATA')):
        FOLDER_PATH = Path(folder_name)

    else:
        FOLDER_PATH = Path.home() / '.wicon'

    FOLDER_PATH.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

    # configure the loggers
    logger_formatter = Formatter(
        fmt="[{asctime}][{process:05}][{name}][{levelname}] {message}",
        style='{'
    )
    logger_file_handler = FileHandler(
        FOLDER_PATH / 'wicon.log',
        mode='a'
    )
    logger_file_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)

    logger = getLogger(__name__)

    src.auth.logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
    src.auth.logger.setLevel(LOGGER_LEVEL)

    src.credentials.logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
    src.credentials.logger.setLevel(LOGGER_LEVEL)

    logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
    logger.setLevel(LOGGER_LEVEL)

    # set the paths for individual files
    CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = FOLDER_PATH / "credentials.json"
    SETTINGS_FILE_PATH = FOLDER_PATH / "wicon-settings.json"

    # load the user settings
    USER_SETTINGS = load_settings(SETTINGS_FILE_PATH, logger)

    return USER_SETTINGS, CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH, logger


def define_and_read_args(arguments: list[str]) -> ArgNamespace:
    """configure parsers
    - define the main parser for the application executable
    - define subparsers (one for each functionality)
    - parse the arguments"""

    main_parser = ArgumentParser(
        prog='wicon',
        description="Connects your Wi-Fi in UNIVERSITY_NAME."
    )
    functions = main_parser.add_subparsers(required=True)

    connect_parser = functions.add_parser(
        'login',
        help="Login to the Wi-Fi network."
    )
    connect_parser.set_defaults(func=connect)
    connect_parser.add_argument(
        '-r',
        '--registernumber',
        type=str,
        help="You UNIVERSITY_NAME register number"
    )
    connect_parser.add_argument(
        '-p',
        '--password',
        type=str,
        help="Your UNIVERSITY_NAME Wi-Fi password"
    )

    disconnect_parser = functions.add_parser(
        'logout',
        help="Logout of the Wi-Fi network."
    )
    disconnect_parser.set_defaults(func=disconnect)

    add_credentials = functions.add_parser(
        'addcreds',
        help="Add/update your register number and password."
    )
    add_credentials.set_defaults(func=addcreds)

    purge_credentials = functions.add_parser(
        'purgecreds',
        help="Remove your register number and password."
    )
    purge_credentials.set_defaults(func=purgecreds)

    return main_parser.parse_args(arguments)


def connect(parsed_arguments: ArgNamespace) -> str:
    """log in to the Wi-Fi network
    - check if on UNIVERSITY_NAME network
    - get credentials and handle relevant CLI arguments
    - send the request
    - return the response/status"""

    if not src.auth.check_ssid(src.auth.get_ssid()):
        return 'not-on-university_name'

    logger.info("Attempting to login.")

    try:
        credentials = src.credentials.load_credentials(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)

    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        return 'no-credentials'

    # prioritize the arguments
    # so if a credential is available as an argument, override the credential from file
    if parsed_arguments.registernumber:
        credentials['register-number'] = parsed_arguments.registernumber

    if parsed_arguments.password:
        credentials['password'] = parsed_arguments.password

    if not (('register-number' in credentials) and ('password' in credentials)):
        logger.warning("Possibly missing credentials.")

    return src.auth.login(credentials)


def disconnect(parsed_arguments: ArgNamespace) -> str:
    """log out of the Wi-Fi network
    - check if on UNIVERSITY_NAME network
    - send the request
    - return the response/status"""

    if not src.auth.check_ssid(src.auth.get_ssid()):
        return 'not-on-university_name'
    
    logger.info("Attempting to logout.")

    return src.auth.logout()


def addcreds(parsed_arguments: ArgNamespace) -> str:
    """store/edit user credentials
    - get user credentials
    - validate credentials
    - store credentials to file
    - verify the file"""

    logger.info("Attempting to add/edit credentials.")

    try:
        register_number = input("Enter your register number: ")

        if not src.credentials.REGISTER_NUMBER_REGEX.match(register_number):
            raise ValueError("Invalid register number.")
        else:
            logger.info("Register number is valid.")

        password = getpass("Enter your password: ")
        confirm_password = getpass("Re-enter your password: ")

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise ValueError("Passwords do not match.")
        else:
            logger.info("Passwords match.")

    except ValueError as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        print(e.args[0])

    else:
        src.credentials.add_credentials(
            CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH, register_number, password
        )

        credentials = src.credentials.load_credentials(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)

        # ensure that the correct credentials were stored in the file
        if credentials and credentials.get('register-number') == register_number and credentials.get('password') == password:
            print(f"{Fore.GREEN}{Style.BRIGHT}Credentials added successfully.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
            return 'credadd-success'

    print(f"{Fore.RED}{Style.BRIGHT}Failed to add credentials.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
    return 'credadd-failure'


def purgecreds(parsed_arguments: ArgNamespace) -> str:
    """purge user credentials
    - delete credentials file
    - verify that the file has been deleted"""

    logger.info("Attempting to purge credentials.")

    try:
        src.credentials.purge_credentials(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
    
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        print(e.args[0])

    else:
        if not CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH.exists():
            print(f"{Fore.GREEN}{Style.BRIGHT}Credentials purged successfully.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
            return 'credpurge-success'

    print(f"{Fore.RED}{Style.BRIGHT}Failed to purge credentials.{Style.RESET_ALL}")
    return 'credpurge-failure'


def main(arguments: list[str]) -> None:
    """main function
    - parses the command line arguments
    - initialize the database
    - calls the appropriate function based on the arguments"""

    # parse the command line arguments
    parsed_namespace = define_and_read_args(arguments)
    try:
        status_message: str = parsed_namespace.func(parsed_namespace)

    # notify the user if an error occurs
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        notification = Notify(
            default_notification_title="Error",
            default_notification_message=e.args[0],
            default_notification_application_name="Wi-Con"
        )

        notification.send(block=False)

    else:
        # check whether the status message should trigger a notification
        current_status: dict[str, dict[str, str | bool]] = USER_SETTINGS.get('notification-settings', dict()).get(status_message, DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION)  # type: ignore
        
        # if the status is an abnormal behaviour or failure, notify the user
        if current_status.get('notification', True):
            notification = Notify(
                default_notification_title=current_status.get('title', DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION['title']),  # type: ignore
                default_notification_message=current_status.get('message', DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION['message']),  # type: ignore
                default_notification_application_name="Wi-Con"
            )

            notification.send(block=False)

        logger.info(status_message)

    logger.info("Exit.")
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    USER_SETTINGS, CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH, logger = init(__name__)
    main(argv[1:])
```

Comment: may want to use https://pypi.org/project/keyring/ instead of storing passwords in clear text